# Sending direct message to a bot in slack and get the response

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to figure out how to send a direct message to a bot in slack using the Slack API and get the response by the bot. For example, I use chat.postMessage:

> curl -X POST -d
>   'token=xoxp-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx&channel=BOT_ID&text=where?&as_user=true'
>   https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage

The bot respond with:

> I'm at hubot-server1.local
> I'm at hubot-server2.local

I want to capture the response. What Slack API I can use to capture? chat.postMessage doesn't return it.

Thanks for any reply.

Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no API methods that will directly return a response from a bot. To capture responses of bots (and users) you need to read the messages from a channel.

With the Web API you can do that by calling [`channels.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) for public channels (or [`groups.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.history) private channels and similar names methods for other conversation types. you can also use the new [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) method to access all types of channels).

Those methods will give you all messages of a channel and you will need to filter out the right message within your app.

You can also get all new messages for a channel with the [RTM API](https://api.slack.com/rtm) and the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api).